# What is 'yarn init -2'?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, yarn-v2

Trying to create a react app.
I used yarn init -2 to create a project.
But not able to find much details on this command.
I would like to know what does `yarn init -2` do?

Comment: Are you sure this is a valid command? According to [docs](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/init/) You can only use 2 flags i.e `-p` and `-y`. There is nothing like `-2`

Comment: yes it is. I ran the command from vs code terminal.
it creates files like .editorconfig, .gitattributes, .gitignore, .yarnrc.yml, readme.md .....

need to run the command "yarn" first, then "yarn init -2"

Comment: @DecPK that's the docs for `classic yarn`, this command is from the [modern yarn installation docs](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install)

Answer (score 1):

It's to setup Yarn's PnP and Zero-Installs features.

[Docs](https://v3.yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#initializing-your-project):

> By default, `yarn init -2` will setup your project to be compatible with
> Zero-Installs, which requires checking-in your cache in your
> repository; check your .gitignore if you wish to disable this.